# Qt Localization with a variable

Tags: qt

I would like to translate weather conditions in my code but am having a little trouble.

Example:

English - Cloudy

French - Nuageux

```
weatherString = hash["weather"];
weatherBytes = weatherString.toLocal8Bit();
weatherCharArray = weatherBytes.data();

qDebug() << "Current Weather: " << QObject::tr(weatherCharArray);
```

The weather comes in from a web service so it's always different. I knew that the code above would not create the entries automatically in my .ts files as they are only known at runtime, so I tried to manually enter them.

```
<message>
<source>Cloudy</source>
<translation>Nuageux</translation>
</message>
```

But everytime I compile it puts in:

```
type="obsolete"
```

In my translation tag, what should I do??

Comment: I suppose obsolete tag means only that `Cloudy` was not found in source files, so Qt thinks it was removed (hence, it is obsolete). But I do not see how tag prevents translating. If it bothers you, just create `QMap<QString, QString>` with key being english word and value being result of `tr(key)`.

Comment: The tag does seem to prevent translation unfortunately.

Comment: `lrelease` docs [says](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtlinguist/linguist-manager.html#using-lrelease) that it only compiles translations tagged as `finished`. So you should either modify tags before launching `lrealease` (e.g. with custom utility and specific translator comments) or put all the strings from server in source code somehow.

Comment: Yes I can add all the strings from the server as I know every possible string that it produces, and I would like to do that. Can I manually set a tag to finished? I tried and it goes back to obsolete.

Comment: It does not 'goes back', `lupdate` updates it since it can not find source string in sources; and I don't know how to force it not to (except removing manually added messages completely, adding strings to sources with proper `tr()` calls and letting `lupdate` do its job).

Comment: I think I might have no choice but to do that, seems a little odd though doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the ways I have implemented a solution to this problem.

```
// setup (in my constructor before any use of mytr function
this->availableTranslations();
```

In my cpp file...

```
QMap <QString, QString> SettingsWidget::trMap;

void SettingsWidget::availableTranslations()
{
     if(trMap.size() != 0)
          return;
     trMap["true"] = tr("True","settings option");
     trMap["false"] = tr("False","settings option");
     trMap["Auto"] = tr("Auto","settings option");
     trMap["None"] = tr("None","settings option");
     trMap["smallest"] = tr("Smallest","settings option");
     trMap["very small"] = tr("Very Small","settings option");
     trMap["small"] = tr("Small","settings option");
     trMap["medium"] = tr("Medium","settings option");
     trMap["large"] = tr("Large","settings option");
     trMap["very large"] = tr("Very Large","settings option");
     trMap["Advanced"] = tr("Advanced","settings option");
     trMap["Basic"] = tr("Basic","settings option");
}

QString SettingsWidget::mytr(QString s)
{
     if(trMap.contains(s))
          return trMap[s];//qApp->translate("SettingsWidget",qPrintable(s));
     else
          return s;
}
```

Then when I am using the above on the fly it looks like this:

```
// in use
mytr(list.at(currIndex));
```

You will notice that with this setup, it can look up a translation based on a variable instead of only a `char *`, and it puts it in the translation file properly without too much extra work or maintenance.

Hope that helps.